# Start 32 bit Windows on Virtualbox without VT-X

Tags: virtualbox, 32-bit, vt-x

Since my main PC went down, I swapped my HDD to an old PC that doesn't support VT-X at all, while the broken one does.

The problem is, my guest is a 32 bit Windows 7 that doesn't want to start because Virtualbox says my CPU doesn't suppport VT-X, even if I modify the VM's .vbox.

Is there any way to get rid of this problem, knowing that a 32 bit Windows 7 Virtualbox guest do actually work without VT-X ?

Edit:

The problem solved by itself, I don't even know why. Or a reboot of my host maked it or Virtualbox made a good refresh of the .vbox file. They are the only explanations I can have.

Comment: You should have no problem running a 32-bit guest operating system within a virtual machine on a 32-bit operating system even if it doesn't have VT-x.  There is more going on but the lack of detail makes it not possible to even guess what that might be.

Comment: are you able to disable it under Settings -> System -> Acceleration? I know you can't disable I/O APIC, once the OS is installed, but I believe you can disable PAE/NX and VT-x, as long as the VM is not booted.

Comment: The problem solved by itself, I don't even know why.
Or a reboot of my host maked it or Virtualbox made a good refresh of the .vbox file.
They are the only explanations I can have.