# Running 32 bit OS on 64 bit OS host without VT-x

Tags: virtual-machine, 64-bit, virtualization, vmware-player, vt-x

I am trying to run a 32 bit OS ([Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/)) in VMware Player. It is coming up with the error 'VT-x is not available', even though I have a 64 bit CPU/host OS. Why is this?

I am aware that you cannot virtualise a 64 bit OS inside a 64 bit OS without VT-x, but I assumed this would not be the case for 32 bit. How might I solve this, am I missing a detail here? The CPU I am using is an Intel Pentium p6200, which does not support VT-x. *I do not have the option of VT-x. Am I still able to virtualise 32 bit OSes?*

I am considering using software virtualisation, such as QEMU, but I would prefer not to because of the slowdown involved.

Comment: Depending on how the VM is set up, it may require VT-x. Check its configuration. I’m not sure if VMware Player shows all the relevant options.

Comment: I've tried that. You can change very little, although i have tried changing 'virtualise Intel VT-x' on and off, but i believe that is for the vm's CPU, and will not affect the problem

Comment: I’d like to check the `.vmx` file of your VM. How did you create it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VT-x is not available, but is enabled in BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1153470/vt-x-is-not-available-but-is-enabled-in-bios)

Comment: @DanielB i created it through player, using the default options. There doesn't seem to be anywhere to change, view or specify the OS or CPU bits for the vm in player. I could try pro.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, as i said, VT-x is not enabled, as my CPU does not support it

Comment: @DanielB My .vmx is here https://filebin.net/amrned56paf24o4j . Would you need any other files?

Comment: 32-bit guest is always supported regardless of VT-x. If you have any problems then probably you have some wrong configuration while creating/importing the VM https://superuser.com/q/773338/241386 https://serverfault.com/q/109161 could you copy and paste the vmx file here

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I'll Check up on that. you can't copy and paste the .vmx file easily, but it is here: https://filebin.net/amrned56paf24o4j/Android.vmx?t=ihyzm8h4

Comment: There are lots of 64-but processors that don’t support VT-x or ANDs equivalent virtualization feature.

Comment: I tried it on virtual box and it worked - must be a problem with vmware player, or config, as Daniel pointed out

Comment: Are your sure you have download a 32-bit version of "Android-x86"? Because it has 64-bit versions too. For example, you should download `android-x86-7.1-r2.i686.rpm`, not `android-x86-7.1-r2.x86_64.rpm`. Not everyone knows that x64 is actually part of the x86 architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Remove from the `.vmx` file the following lines:

- `vvtd.enable = "TRUE"`
- `vhv.enable = "TRUE"`

It *may* then work. It could result in abysmal performance and/or crashes, too.

I suggest using an advanced editor like Notepad++ to edit the file. You can also use WordPad.

**Update**

The following lines are also relevant (though not present in this case):

- `monitor.virtual_mmu = "software"`
- `monitor.virtual_exec = "software"`

The value can be either `software`, `hardware` or `automatic`. `automatic` is the default value.

In VMware Workstation 12, I have the following options:

[image]

The mode dropdown has the following options, which result in the following `virtual_exec`/`virtual_mmu` values:

- “Automatic”: `automatic`/`automatic`
- “Binary translation”: `software`/`software`
- “Intel VT-x or AMD-V”: `hardware`/`software`
- “Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI”: `hardware`/`hardware`

Additionally, the checkboxes toggle the following options:

- “Disable acceleration for binary translation”: `disable_acceleration = "TRUE"`
- “Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI”: `vhv.enable = "TRUE"`
- “Virtualize CPU performance counters”: `vpmc.enable = "TRUE"`

Except disabling acceleration, all options require CPU support.

Because VMware Player does not offer access to all options it supports, you need to edit the `.vmx` file manually. It’s a regular text file, though it may not have Windows line breaks.